# Optimization of multivariate function with a initial solution close to the optimum

Tags: algorithm, optimization, numerical

I was wondering if anyone knows which kind of algorithm could be use in my case. I already have run the optimizer on my multivariate function and found a solution to my problem, assuming that my function is regular enough.  I slightly perturbate the problem and would like to find the optimum solution which is close to my last solution. Is there any very fast algorithm in this case or should I just fallback to a regular one.

Comment: are you talking about solving equations?

Comment: yes, will make my question more precise.

Comment: Which "optimizer" did you run? What yo you mean with "PB"? What algorithms do consider as "regular"? Are you doing optimization on a beginner level, or have you made yourself already through the "Numerical Recipes" book (http://www.nrbook.com/a/bookcpdf.php)? If you don't want your question to be closed as "too broad", please clarify.

Comment: @Doc Brown: I have run Powell method on my function ( but I could have used any other algorithm, as the first solution is not the one i need to get quickly). This first solution is going to be the initial solution for my next optimization which is the one I want to get as quicky as possible.

Comment: @Dave: there are a lot of different optimization algorithms available, which one to use depends much on what kind of function you have (how many variables, linear, discrete, differentiable, quadratic, convex, is existence an optimum guaranteed? Hard to answer your question if you don't provide more details.

Comment: @Doc Brown: My pb has many variables ( let say 100 ) and is non linear ( but not wild , i try to minimize many function like 1/(1+x)^t where i search for x). The question was more a genral question rather than to solve my explicit pb. It is just that if you try to use the most advanced algo it may try first to compute the Jacobian and the Hessian , recompute the value of my objective function and that may take much more time than an adhoc simpler method

Comment: @Dave: the most advanced algos *avoid* computing of the Hessian. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

We probably need a bit more information about your problem; but since you know you're near the right solution, and if derivatives are easy to calculate, [Newton-Raphson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method_in_optimization) is a sensible choice, and if not, [Conjugate-Gradien](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method)t may make sense.

Comment: Newton-Raphson is a root solving technique, not an optimization one. Also, conjugate gradient *may* make sense, but depending on available information, there are plenty of other choices.

Comment: @Alexandre: Any root-finding algorithm also doubles as an optimization one if you search for points where the gradient vanishes. [Newton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method_in_optimization) is the canonical algorithm for when you are already near the desired extrema.

Comment: @missingno: This is very difficult to put into practice as is since you have to compute the Hessian matrix, or an approximation of it (if you have 1000 variables, this is a 1000x1000 matrix). Quasi-Newton methods (also called "variable metric" methods) are all about this (there are plenty of them, Wikipedia is a good start), and really take into account the fact that near a minimum, you look like a quadratic. Also, minimization techniques can be used to solve for f(x) = 0 (eg. by minimizing f(x)^2). So both fields are related, but quite different (and have different difficulties).

Comment: Yes, it's almost as if we need more information about the problem, as I said.

Comment: Well, Newton is still the canonical algo though. There is a reason Quasi-Newton methods are called Quasi-Newton :P

Answer (score 1):

If you already have an iterative optimizer (for example, based on Powell's direction set method, or CG), why don't you use your initial solution as a starting point for the next run of your optimizer?

EDIT: due to your comment: if calculating the Jacobian or the Hessian matrix gives you performance problems, try BFGS  (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BFGS_method), it avoids calculation of the Hessian completely; here
http://www.alglib.net/optimization/lbfgs.php you find a (free-for-non-commercial) implementation of BFGS. A good description of the details you will [here](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http://orbit.dtu.dk/getResource?recordId=201104&objectId=1&versionId=1&ei=C7DwTZaFHYPNswa_qqmHBw&usg=AFQjCNEPJnoTZ9X8GT67r0Q43wAPGUbEWw&sig2=sjYSKKkzKgYoLnKq0wPHEA).

And don't expect to get anything from finding your initial solution with a less sophisticated algorithm.

So this is all about *unconstrained* optimization. If you need information about *constrained* optimization, I suggest you google for "SQP".

Comment: Thx very much , will have a look at it.

Comment: BFGS is usually a sound first choice. Levenberg-Marquardt is too.

Answer (score 0):

there are a bunch of algorithms for finding the roots of equations.  If you know approximately where the root is, there are algorithms that will get you arbitrarily close very quickly, in `ln n` time or better.

One is [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method)

another is the [Bisection Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method)

Note that these algorithms are for single variable functions, but can be expanded to multivariate functions.

Comment: We are talking optimization, not root solving. They are related, but very different.

Comment: And what the heck does `n` refer to here ?

Answer (score 0):

*Every* minimization algorithm performs better (read: perform at all) if you have a good initial guess. The initial guess for the perturbed problem will be in your case the minimum point of the non perturbed problem.

Then, you have to specify your requirements: you want speed. What accuracy do you want ? Does space efficiency matters ? Most importantly: what information do you have: only the value of the function, or do you also have the derivatives (possibly second derivatives) ?

Some background on the problem would help too. Looking for a smooth function which has been discretized will be very different than looking for hundreds of unrelated parameters.

Global information (ie. is the function convex, is there a guaranteed global minimum or many local ones, etc) can be left aside for now. If you have trouble finding the minimum point of the perturbed problem, this is something you will have to investigate though.

Answering these questions will allow us to select a particular algorithm. There are many choices (and trade-offs) for multivariate optimization.

Also, which is quicker will very much depend on the problem (rather than on the algorithm), and should be determined by experimentation.

Comment: I agree with everything here. But as a general method would you try to reuse the same algorithm that generated the first initial solution. Imagine the first solution has been generated with the help of Jacobian + Hessian . A simple perturbation of the pb should not involve the recalculation of these quantities. Derivative free algorithm may converge quicker or freezing the jacobian and reusing it may be another trick. What do you think?

Comment: @Dave: This is not a good idea. By definition, the Jacobian will be zero at the first initial solution, and will be non zero (it will basically tell you where to go !) after perturbation. Nevertheless, you can reuse the Hessian (or its approximation if you went Quasi-Newton). But this is premature optimization.

Comment: You are right my jacobian will be zero because i am working on a least square problem. So locally my function behave like F(x0) + H(F)(x0). Is there some way to reuse the Hessian to reduce the dimension of my problem (PCA like method) ( using eigenvectors for inst and updatign them with quasi-newton method ...)?

Answer (score -1):

Thought I don't know much about using computers in this capacity, I remember an article that used neuroevolutionary techniques to find "best-fit" equations relatively efficiently, given a known function complexity (linear, Nth-polynomial, exponential, logarithmic, etc) and a set of point plots. As I recall it was one of the earliest uses of what we now know as computational neuroevolution; because the functional complexity (and thus the number of terms) of the equation is known and fixed, a static neural net can be used and seeded with your closest values, then "mutated" and tested for fitness, with heuristics to make new nets closer to existing nets with high fitness. Using multithreading, many nets can be created, tested and evaluated in parallel.

Comment: There is no need for this kind of heuristical technique in most cases. Linear/Nonlinear optimization is a very well studied field, and there are many algorithms that guarantee better performance and acuracy (depending on the function to be potimized, of course)